# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT/sigterm in spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Ive already tried connecting the IB outlets in spritekit but it didnt work. Im getting sigabrt in my gamescene for one of my code lines but I dont think its my code. Ive also been getting sigaterm in my app delelagate for quite some time now. Is this the reason why my app is not working properly even though my code is correct. I dont know if I need to post my code here as well

```
if  (firstBody.categoryBitMask & enemyCategory) != 0
        && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) != 0 {
        enemyCollidedWithPlayer(enemyNode: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, playerNode: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode);
    }
```

Comment: You don't perhaps have two functions connected to your IBActions in the storyboard?

Comment: I dont think so, im new so im not 100% sure. Does this mean i add a button and have its connection for action instead of outlet?

Comment: Almost, but no - when you have two IBActions set you usually get a crash when you click. Sorry I guess I can't help you, try and explain your problem better, perhaps show some code.

Comment: The error pops up right under as! at the end of the code. I dont even have to click the screen, right when i run my app, the error pops up

Comment: You're force unwrapping a variable that has no value in it then.